# How to store account information in Xamarin.iOS Azure Mobile App?

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I use Twitter to authenticate users in an Azure Mobile App.  I want to save the account information on the phone so that users don't have to log in each time the app starts.  It's a Xamarin.iOS app.

If I were building a Windows app, I'd use PasswordVault as explained in [the Azure Mobile Apps documentation under "Caching the authentication token"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/).

If I were using Xamarin.Auth, I'd use the `AccountStore` as explained in [the Xamarin.Auth documentation under "Storing and Retrieving Account Information on Devices"](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/).

I see that the Azure Mobile App SDK contains [a modified version of the Xamarin.Auth plugin](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/tree/master/src/External).  Can I use the `AccountStore` that way?

If not, what's the best way to save account information in Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the iOS Keychain.  I forgot that Xamarin.Auth is open source.  Here's how it stores accounts:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Auth.iOS/KeyChainAccountStore.cs

There's also a Keychain sample from Xamarin:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/Keychain/Main.cs